# When does Identity's UserManager not support lockouts?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

ASP.NET Core Identity has [`UserManager.SupportsUserLockout()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.supportsuserlockout#microsoft-aspnetcore-identity-usermanager-1-supportsuserlockout), which for me is true.

Description:

> Gets a flag indicating whether the backing user store supports user lock-outs.

Is it ever possible for the user manager NOT to support lockouts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it ever possible for the user manager NOT to support lockouts?

**Yes**

Under any of these 2 circumstances:

- `UserManager<TUser>` is subclassed and the `virtual bool SupportsUserLockout` property is overridden and that implementation returns `false`.
- `UserManager<TUser>.Store` (your `IUserStore<TUser>` implementation) does not implement the **optional** `IUserLockoutStore<TUser>` interface.

---

- If you're using the "stock" in-box ASP.NET Core Identity functionality, without using any custom `IUserStore` implementation (and without subclassing `UserManager<TUser>`), then your runtime `IUserStore<TUser>` will be some [subclass of `abstract class UserStoreBase<...>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.userstorebase-5?view=aspnetcore-6.0) which *does* implement `IUserLockoutStore<TUser>`.

  - e.g. *ASP.NET Core Identity for Entity Framework* uses `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore` which inherits the `IUserLockoutStore<TUser>` interface implementation.
- Because in C#/.NET, interfaces are strictly additive (one cannot "remove" an interface from a class - you can only reimplement it) it means if you don't want to subclass `UserManager<TUser>` then you will cannot use a subclass `UserStoreBase<>` as the basis for your reimplementation of `IUserStore<>` - you'll have to start from scratch, basically.

  - (Which in my mind, at least, means that ASP.NET Core Identity's default combination of `UserManager` and `UserStoreBase<...>` is a bad OOP design because it requires implementations to actively go through a lot of effort to correctly *not* support something, instead of making everything opt-in.
  - [*Hey kids, inheritance is bad, mmm'key*](https://boxbase.org/entries/2020/aug/3/case-against-oop/) (okay, not "bad", but at least is so *fraught with problems* it should be avoided.

    - Subclass inheritance is a blunt instrument, especially in C# and Java, where it's impossible to separate a type's "interface"1 from implementation, and can't describe a type's interface in a *type algebraic* way - so we can't define a `class Derived` that subclasses a parent `class Base : ISomeInterface` such that `class Derived` *no longer* implements `ISomeInterface` (the best we can do is either abuse implicit conversions to a separate type, or "hide" members with `[EditorBrowsable]` and reimplement the interface explicitly with `throw new NotSupportedException()`, which is horrible, but even Microsoft does it in some places in .NET's base libraries, such as in `Stream` and `TextWriter` subclasses).
    - (Also, don't (ab)use inheritance just to have "common members" in different types. I agree that *it does suck* that C#/.NET still doesn't support mixins, but the drudgery of copy+pasting forwarder properties and methods around is less painful in the long-term than dealing with the consequences of inappropriate use of inheritance.

[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.userstorebase-5?view=aspnetcore-6.0): By "interface" I don't mean `interface` types; I mean the set of `public` members of a `class` or `struct`, i.e. a type's exposed surface.

---

(In an earlier edit of my post, I suggested that `IConfigureOptions<LockoutOptions>` could be used to configure `SupportsUserLockout`, however I was wrong: as there is no option to outright disable the lockout system, but if you were to subclass both `LockoutOptions` to add a `bool Enabled` property *and* subclass `UserManager<TUser>` to specify `override bool SupportsUserLockout` to return `LockoutOptions.Enabled` (<sub>ideally, from an immutable copy, not the original mutable options object</sub>) then that would work.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. The answer is a bit more complicated, one moment while I finish my writing.

Comment: @ionix I've significantly revised my answer.

Comment: So basically what you're saying, is you're a huge fan of the UserManager implementation ;)